# Merge two JSON Objects based on condition using c#

Tags: c#

Need to merge two json objects using c# based on spectific condition. If source JSON has "Enabled" property as "false" and destination JSON has same property as "true", then need to replace the value. Other wise no need to replace keep as same.

I tried like this :

```
o1.Merge(o2, new JsonMergeSettings
{
    MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Merge
});
```

its overlapping the whole Object. Need to merge based on condition. Thanks in advance.

```
JSON 1: 

{
  "Name": "Sample",
  "Array": [],
  "Actions": [
    {
      "Name": "A",
      "Enabled": false
    },
    {
      "Name": "B",
      "Enabled": true
    }
  ]
}

JSON 2 :

{
  "Name": "Sample",
  "Array": [],
  "Actions": [
    {
      "Name": "A",
      "Enabled": true
    },
    {
      "Name": "B",
      "Enabled": false
    }
  ]
}

I need Result JSON as below.

{
  "Name": "Sample",
  "Tabs": [],
  "Actions": [
    {
      "Name": "A",
      "Enabled": true
    },
    {
      "Name": "B",
      "Enabled": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You have to write your own code. If you have written your code and it isn't working you can [edit] your question and include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

> If source JSON has "Enabled" property as "false" and destination JSON has same property as "true", then need to replace the value. Other wise no need to replace keep as same.

One approach would be to,

1. Loop through `Actions` array in the destination json.
2. Read each object's `Name` and `Enabled` from the above array.
3. Retrieve the same object from source json.
4. Read its `Name` and `Enabled`.
5. Check whether property `Name` of both objects from json match and also check `Enabled` property of object from source json is `false` and `Enabled` property of object from destination json is `true`.
6. Rewrite the value of the property `Enabled` to `true`.

---

```
string json1 = "Your source json";
string json2 = "Your destination json";

JObject jObject1 = JObject.Parse(json1);
JObject jObject2 = JObject.Parse(json2);

//1
foreach (JObject obj2 in (JArray)jObject2["Actions"])
{
    //2
    var key2 = obj2["Name"].ToObject<string>();
    var value2 = obj2["Enabled"].ToObject<bool>();

    //3
    var obj1 = jObject1["Actions"].Where(x => x["Name"].ToString() == key2).FirstOrDefault();

    //4
    var key1 = obj1["Name"].ToObject<string>();
    var value1 = obj1["Enabled"].ToObject<bool>();

    //5
    if (key1 == key2 && value1 == false && value2 == true)
    {
        //6
        obj2["Enabled"] = true;
    }
}

string outputJson = jObject2.ToString();
```